# Reduce Windows Error Reporting files / filesize?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, windows-error-reporting, error-logging

My WER is 8GB

[image: 8GB]

. I have an SSD, so I imagine having 8GB of errors reported (most of them warning, as I can see) is quite a bit writting on the SSD.

I never needed it. But I don't want to turn the service off because for the off-chance that I might need it.

Is there any way to reduce the amount of data written in any way?

Comment: If you don't currently have problems, you should purge your current reports, you are going to have to purge some of the data no matter what.  You can use the disk cleanup tool to purge the current data.

Comment: It's not the purging I have a trouble with, it's the amount of data constantly being written. That's 8GB of Windows Error Reporting. I want to reduce it.

Comment: WER is either enabled or disabled.  I would just run a scheduled task to clear it monthly.  Just write a batch script that deletes the contents of `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER` every month.

Comment: you have a lot of app crashes or blue screens. look in eventlog why you get those issues

Comment: Turn Off Windows error reporting.

Comment: Excatly what I DON'T want. Turn off WER. Tune DOWN, yes. Turn OFF, no!

Comment: have you looked in eventlog which applications crashed?